How Does Reed-Solomon Erasure Code Split Data in Rust?
Body:
I'm working on a project in Rust where I'm using the reed_solomon_erasure crate to implement Reed-Solomon erasure codes for data encoding and fault tolerance. I'm struggling to understand how the data is split into shards before applying the erasure codes. Specifically, I want to know how the crate manages splitting the original data into data shards and then generating parity shards.
Here’s an outline of my setup:
I have n total shards: k data shards and r parity shards.
I'm using the ReedSolomon::new(data_shards, parity_shards) function from the reed_solomon_erasure crate to create an instance of the Reed-Solomon encoder.
My Questions:
How exactly is the data split into k data shards by the reed_solomon_erasure crate?
How are the parity shards generated after the data is split?
What role does the SHARD_BYTES_NUMBER play in determining how the data is chunked?
Here is a simplified version of the code I am using
use reed_solomon_erasure::galois_8::ReedSolomon;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct ReedSolomonWrapper {
    inner: ReedSolomon,
}

impl ReedSolomonWrapper {
    pub fn new(data_shards: usize, total_shards: usize) -> Self {
        let inner = ReedSolomon::new(data_shards, total_shards - data_shards).unwrap();
        Self { inner }
    }

    pub fn encode(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Result<HashMap<usize, Vec<u8>>, String> {
        // Split data into shards here
        let shard_byte_number = 1024; // Example
        let mut shards: Vec<Vec<u8>> = data
            .chunks(shard_byte_number)
            .map(|chunk| chunk.to_vec())
            .collect();
        // Continue with encoding logic...
        Ok(HashMap::new()) // Simplified
    }
}


